# Why this is a bogus solution to integral of dx/(x^2 +3)

Tags: integration

The correct solution was

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ $arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})$ $+$ $C$

The solution below is $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
But i still don't know what is wrong with the solution ? (i'm beginner at math)

$\int{\frac{dx}{x^2 + 3}}$ $=$ $\int{\frac{dx}{3(\frac{x^2}{3} + 1)}}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{3}\int{\frac{dx}{(\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{3})^2} + 1)}}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{3}\int{\frac{dx}{((\frac{x}{(\sqrt{3})})^2 + 1)}}$
$=$ $\frac{1}{3}$ $arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})$ $+$ $C$

Comment: The last equality of yours is incorrect. You need $d\left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right)$ in place of $dx$ to use the known integral leading to the inverse tangent. To see this, note that $$
\int {\frac{{d\left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right)^2  + 1}}} \mathop  = \limits^{t = x/\sqrt 3 } \int {\frac{{dt}}{{t^2  + 1}}}  = \arctan t + C = \arctan \left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt 3 }}} \right) + C.
$$

Comment: ah , thanks , i understand now

Comment: i didnt know about that , i will search it later , might as well make that comment as answer

Comment: It is integration by substitution.